# CSS display table ignores width

Tags: html, css

I have multiple li items floating left and I want to set a right border around them so that all of them get the same height for the border. Therefor I'm using the `display:table;` However it ignores the width of the li. How can I force to use same width for all li items?

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li><img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7437/9982948185_19ae813ee0_n.jpg"/></li>
    <li>b</li>    
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{
    display: table;
}

ul li{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50px !important;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/xbmEQ/

Answer (score 3):

You can try "table-layout: fixed"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Answer (score 1):

Your image is bigger so you are having issues. Set max-width to image:

```
ul li img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Also use word break on li,

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/xbmEQ/7/

Comment: The image is not the problem. The idea was that if I have specified the width for the li, it should hide the overflowing content instead of increasing the width.

Comment: Nope, its not the way <table>, <td>, <th> works. These elements will expand itself to contain the content inside it. This is the beauty of tables. Using word-break would break texts to fall in next line and setting image max-height for image means you are safer!

Comment: @user2738640 this is best answer. So I think you should accept this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need to define the width for the img tag because img tag is taking full width So you can set the image width to 50px but better way to define width 100%.

If you don't want to specify anything inside the li tag then you may set `display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;` to your `li` instead of using `display: table-cell;` to `li`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xbmEQ/10/)

Answer (score 0):

not real sure what you're trying to achive but what about this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbmEQ/1/)

```
ul{}

ul li{
     display: inline-block;
     width: 50px;
     border: 1px solid red;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

**EDITED FIDDLE AND CSS**, added height attribute.
[fiddle 2.0](http://jsfiddle.net/xbmEQ/13/)

```
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'm using display table because I want to have the same height for each of the li (for the border).

Comment: @user2738640 that is no reason to use display:table; --> http://jsfiddle.net/xbmEQ/13/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make the image 50px wide? In that case you just have to add this piece of code:

```
ul li img{
    width: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xbmEQ/3/

Comment: important isn't necessary, removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `min-width` of the `li` items so that they do not shrink below `50px`.

http://jsfiddle.net/xbmEQ/5/

It keeps the `height`s of all the `li` items matching (and dynamic) as you want for matching border heights. It also keeps all the `li` items `50px` wide unless their content exceeds `50px` (like your image).

(I have not tested this in any other browser than Chrome)